# Css: position and z-index ignored and warning shown

Tags: css, css-position, z-index, absolute

I am building a card, click to flip it. but the user will be unable to select the content, I do not want to mess with `document.onselectionchange`, therefore I added a copy button to every card at the top right corner.

however, in this css layout, I can never click the button. I inspected the elements, find that some properties on `.copiable .widget` has issue compiling, specifically:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 200000;
padding: 0;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

there is always an exclainmation mark besides it and I cannot see any helpful warning.

```css
/* card */
.card-wrapper{
    /*
    front: .card-wrapper.card-sides
    back: .card-sides.card-back
    */
    background-color: var(--card-front);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px var(--card-shadow);
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: box-shadow 200ms ease-in, transform 400ms ease-in;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.card-sides{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* cannot set overflow to auto or hidden
    it will hide before or after pseudo-elements */
    color: var(--card-color);
}

.card-wrapper .card-back{
    background-color: var(--card-back);
    color: var(--card-color);
}

.card-wrapper .card-text{
    padding: 15px;
    height: calc(100% - 15px);
    width: calc(100% - 15px);
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    white-space: wrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

.card-wrapper .card-text,
.card-wrapper .card-text > p,
.card-wrapper .card-text > p > p{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-sides.card-on-front{
    background-color: var(--card-back);
    color: var(--card-color);
}

/* copy */
.copiable{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.copiable .widget{
    z-index: 200000;
    text-indent: 0;
    /* end of unsetters */
    position: absolute;
    /* right: 18px; */
    top: 10px;
    content: "double click to selection";
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
}

.widget:hover{
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper card-sides copiable" style="transform: scale(1, 1);">
    <div class="widget copy" style="right: 10px; display: block;">copy</div>
    <div class="cyber-block-wrapper"
        style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: 20000;">
    </div>
    <div class="card-text md-auto-format" style="opacity: 1;">
        <p>
        <p><strong>bold</strong>&nbsp;
            <ins>underline</ins>&nbsp;
            <del>deleted</del> &nbsp;
        </p >
        </p >
    </div>
</div>
```

I will be more than glad if you can give me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cyber-block-wrapper` div covers the entire card and it's in front of your copy button, so it's blocking the clicks (and the hover). If you don't want that to happen you could set `pointer-events: none` on `cyber-block-wrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue was the element stack with z-index however given what you appear to be attempting it feels like a grid may actually work better and moved a lot of style to CSS where it probably belongs better.

I commented out a lot of the CSS and put some updates in there however note the `z-index` part is the critical portion here.

FWIW most often with CSS too much is the issue and removal and simplification and focus on the goal state is a good strategy rather than trying to add MORE.

```js
document.querySelector(".widget.copy").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
  event.currentTarget.dataset.gotclicked = "cheers";
});
```

```css
:root {
  /* patch up the missing variables to prevent errors since no fallback in place */
  --card-front: #00000022;
  --card-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #FF000044;
  --card-color: #0000FFDD;
  --font-size: 16px;
}

.card-wrapper {
  /* this is really the wrapper/parent of all this */
  font-size: var(--font-zize);
  background-color: var(--card-front);
  box-shadow: var(--card-shadow);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1.875em;
  margin-bottom: 1.875em;
  border-radius: 1.25em;
  transition: box-shadow 200ms ease-in, transform 400ms ease-in;
}

.card-sides {
  /* this is really the wrapper/parent of all this */
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  width: 31.25em;
  height: 18.75em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  color: var(--card-color);
}

.widget.copy {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 12;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.widget.copy[data-gotclicked="cheers"] {
  background-color: #FBFB04;
}

.cyber-block-wrapper {
  /* I don't know what this is for but push it back behind so we can click */
  grid-row: 1 / span 8;
  grid-column: 1 / span 12;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px lime;
}

.card-text.md-auto-format {
  opacity: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 7;
  grid-column: 1 / span 12;
  display: grid;
  /* super center the content */
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}


/* does not exist
.card-wrapper .card-back {
  background-color: var(--card-back);
  color: var(--card-color);
}

.card-wrapper .card-text {
  padding: 15px;
  height: calc(100% - 15px);
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  white-space: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.card-wrapper .card-text,
.card-wrapper .card-text>p,
.card-wrapper .card-text>p>p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-sides.card-on-front {
  background-color: var(--card-back);
  color: var(--card-color);
}
*/


/*
.copiable {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
}
*/


/*
.copiable .widget {
  z-index: 200000;
  text-indent: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  content: "double click to selection";
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
}

.widget:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper card-sides copiable">
  <div class="widget copy">copy</div>
  <div class="cyber-block-wrapper">
  </div>
  <div class="card-text md-auto-format">
    <p>
      <p>
        <strong>bold</strong>&nbsp;
        <ins>underline</ins>&nbsp;
        <del>deleted</del>&nbsp;
      </p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note there is a LOT of commented out CSS just for clarity. Added some color and borders just to enhance the change visually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hard work, I need the cyber card wrapper at frontend for decoration, cannot put it behind. @ray’s answer `point-events: none` Perfectly solved the problem, cheers anyway. ^v^

Comment: Another alternative perhaps; "In 3 years will the next developer know why that was done?" Maybe that is you? so might be worth a comment in this case;
Another alternative would be to capture the click event on that other element and propagate that event to the "copy"

Comment: FWIW why `width: 31.25em;` type things here? most browsers default to 16px (which I forced with `--font-size: 16px;` so that is a division of 500 by 16 - could be `rem` instead perhaps if I had force that on the document hrml root but `em` scales with the wrapper which is a "choice" here based on design intent.

Answer (score 0):

> there is always an exclainmation mark besides it and I cannot see any helpful warning.

You are getting a warning in `.copiable .widget` because all properties you named (`position`, `z-index`, `padding`, `transition`) are duplicated.

To solve the "exclamation mark" problem, you can simply remove the duplicates and just keep the value you want to have.
*(E.g.: remove `padding: 5px;` and keep `padding: 0;`, or the other way around)*

**Disable text selection:**
For this, you can use the CSS property `user-select: none;`

Or if you want to stick with your example:

Edit `.copiable .widget` remove the duplicated `z-index: 10;` so that your copy button has a higher z-index than your container `.copiable`.

```
.copiable .widget {
    /* otherattributes */
    z-index: 20000
}

.copiable{ 
     z-index: 2000;
}
```